# ExecuteError: ERROR 000561: Relationship invalid for selected layers. Failed to execute (SelectLayerByLocation)

Tags: python, loops, cursor, arcgis, arcpy

I am working on a code where nhl players in my nhlroster.shp feature class need to play only one of these three positions: leftFeild, rightFeild, Center and all the players must be born in sweden. I keep getting this error for my arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management: RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Users/jessi/Desktop/CPSUGeog485/project3_2021"
cntryFc = "Countries_WGS84.shp"
leftFeild = "LW"
rightFeild = "RW"
Center = "C"
cntryFeild = "CNTRY_name"
cntry = "Sweden"

#Select only players from target country
whereClause = cntryFeild + " =  '" + cntry + "'"
cntryLayer = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(cntryFc, "NEW_SELECTION", whereClause)

#Create Loop for Target Positions
positionList = (leftFeild, rightFeild, Center) 
for plyrPositions in positionList:
    playerQuery = "plyrPosition = '" + plyrPositions + "'"
#Narrow down players born in sweden who play target positions
plyrLayer = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(cntryLayer, "Contains", positionList)
```

Comment: you have a typo in leftField and rightField

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your shapefile into a feature layer with arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management() as noted in the usage document for Select by Location https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-location.htm and Select by Attribute doc https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-attribute.htm; "New Selection" should read "NEW_SELECTION" in your select by attribute line.

Comment: I tried to add the make a feature layer like you suggested but continue to get the same message: invalid relationship for (select by location). arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management('nhlrosters.shp', 'nhlrosters_lyr')
plyrLayer = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management('nhlrosters_lyr', "Contains", cntryLayer)

Comment: so if countryFc becomes countryFc_lyr through your make feature layer line, and you then you make your selection by attributes, then I think you need to feed countryFc_lyr into the select by location query. Try to replace the cntryLayer with the countryFc_lyr. Also post your edits next time so it's easier to follow where you are at.

Comment: I Updated the code above to show where I currently am with the code but I just cant get past the Select By location part. In that section of my code I am trying to narrow down the players born in sweden contained in my cntryLayer with the target positions left,right,and center.